# VBA XMLHTTP Request. Enable to get data in a HTML format for parsing data

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I need to recreate the following table in a spreadsheet. Basically the earnings of US companies for the next week. Countries can be selected using the "Filters" button.

[image]

Although I’m able to get the body of the table, the way the data is coming is as a single string which makes things way more complex to parse. I can't filter by tag, class or any other option.

This is the script I’ve put together.

```
Sub EarningsNextWeek()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim postdata$, URL$

    URL = "https://www.investing.com/earnings-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData"

    XMLReq.Open "POST", URL, False
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
    
    postdata = "country[]=5&currentTab=nextWeek&limit_from=0"
    
    XMLReq.send postdata
    
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & "- " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

End Sub
```

And this is the string I get:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Does anybody find a clever way of doing it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like it is returning json. Either use json parser to pull out the embedded html and then use an html parser, or (less ideal) regex out the string you need and then use html parser. Looks like you will still need to wrap in extracted string in <table> tags so vba html parser doesn't fall over.

Comment: @QHar it looks like json for the first characters, but unfortunately it's not . I've also tried your second suggestion, but I 'm not an HTML expert. I've noticed some HTML code is missing and some escape characters should be removed. I guess my code is not right and there should be an easier way to do it. just my feeling...

Comment: Can you put the full returned string into a pastebin and share a link to that?

Comment: there you go [link](https://hastebin.com/raw/tehomabowo)

Comment: what did you get with just .responsetext? No strconv.

Comment: This is responseText output: [link](https://hastebin.com/raw/xoyebalali)

Comment: I don't currently see an easy way. It is possible to generate html that can be parsed but requires a lot string cleaning on the response as what you are getting back is intended to be handled by a browser.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for yours attempts. I'll see if using IE requests instead makes my life a little bit easier. Not close to any computer for  while, will try when I'm back home. Thx!